# How to instantiate an object in ruby

Tags: ruby

(ruby noob here..apologies if I'm not asking the question correctly)

So I have two files, one contains a module which holds a class....

file_alpha.rb :

```
class alpha
  def a_name
     do stuff
  end
end
```

file_beta.rb:

```
module STUFF_IN_BETA
  class beta
    def b_name
      do more stuff
    end
  end
end
```

So I want to access 'def b_name' inside file_alpha but I'm not sure how...

```
class alpha
  def a_name
     do stuff
     b_name()  <----HOW TO DO this?
  end
end
```

How do I make the method 'b_name' available to class alpha?

Comment: Your question would be more clear if you used sensible identifiers. Neither `a` nor `b` are legal class names, and you re-used both as function names too.

Comment: Are you trying to define a method called `b_name` or call a method called `b_name`? It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your class
require 'b.rb'

And then call the method
b.b()

Answer (score 1):

If you want b to be a module that adds methods to a, ditch the `class` inside it, and just do:

```
class a
  include STUFF_IN_BETA
  def a
    do stuff
    b # this will call method b
  end
end

module STUFF_IN_BETA
  def b
    do more stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: As willglynn pointed out, this is psuedocode; you need to use capitalized (and preferably meaningful) class/module names.

Comment: In the actual code, yes. But the actual code already exist and all test are green. The actual question is more related to the "HOW to do this" part...but I'll go back and update the pseudo code for anyone following this question afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

file_beta.rb

```
module StuffInBeta
  def b
    do more stuff
  end
end
```

file_alpha.rb

```
require 'file_beta' 
class A
  def a
    do stuff
    b          # from the module 
  end
end
```